# Why the inode value of write and re-write file is different

Tags: filesystems, inode, ext3

I created a file called my_file and verfied the inode value. I opened he file again and re-write some more contents. When I viewed the inode size. It varied from the previous inode size. Why isnt the inode same for the file my_file after re-writing on it ?

Comment: What tool did you use to modify the file?  Some editors will write a new file and rename it, deleting the old.

Comment: @Charles : I used the vim editor. You were right when I use cat to modify the file , the inode values are not changed

Comment: @Charles: But why does the vim editor deletes and creates once again a new file ? . Please help me understand .

Comment: As I didn't write vim, I can't answer for sure, but: file renames are atomic, while file rewrites aren't.  A program crash halfway through a new file write won't trash the original file.